# SQL case statement in join condition

Tags: sql

I am trying to achieve a full outer join based on three conditions, all of them linked by logical ANDs. However, the third condition is not always valid: it is based on a column named "counter" which in some cases may be "null" in the table I want to join to.
Let me explain in more detail.
The basic join on statement would look like this:

```
... table1 full outer join table2 
on (table1.1=table2.1 AND table1.2=table2.2 AND table1.counter=table2.counter)
```

Now, however, in some cases table1.counter might be null, whereas table2.counter is not. In these cases, I want the join to happen on the first two conditions and neglect the third one.

My idea was to do it like that:

```
... table1 full outer join table2 
on (table1.1=table2.1 AND table1.2=table2.2 
AND table1.counter= case when table1.counter is null then null 
                         else table2.counter 
                    end)
```

This, however, doesn't work, as the result is exactly the same as in the first code, i.e. the first case statement never gets triggered. But I don't see why?

Any hints or insights would be greatly welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like :

```
AND (table1.counter IS NULL OR table1.counter=table2.counter)
```

Instead of :

```
AND table1.counter=table2.counter
```

In your first query.

Comment: You're welcome, but don't forget to mark this subject as solved ;)